# Code infinitely prints when submitted to zybooks but not in my IDE

Tags: java

EDIT: The problem was that I made the scanner in the ShoppingCartManager and The main. Once I called the scanner from the shoppingCartManager the issue went away.

I am taking a Computer Science program and we have been using Zybooks to submit our code. I have been writing a shopping cart program where there is a menu that prints off options for the user. My code runs fine when using IntelliJ and eclipse but when I submit it to Zybooks the output that it shows for the tests that it runs is a printed prompt infinitely printing.. The following code is the main file with the main in it.

[This is what Zybooks gets for an output (the prompt gets printed until it hits a character limit).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dsQKj.png)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;


public class ShoppingCartManager {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String customerName, currentDate;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter Customer's Name:");
        customerName = sc.nextLine().toString().trim();
        System.out.println("Enter Today's Date:");
        currentDate = sc.nextLine().toString().trim();
        ShoppingCart cart = new ShoppingCart(customerName, currentDate);
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Customer Name: "+cart.getCustomerName());
        System.out.println("Today's Date: "+cart.getDate());
        System.out.println();
        printMenu(cart);
}



/**
 * Prints the menu, and builds the shopping cart
 * object passed in as parameter
 */
private static void printMenu(ShoppingCart cart){

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        char choice = ' ';
        System.out.println("MENU");
        System.out.println("a - Add item to cart");
        System.out.println("d - Remove item from cart");
        System.out.println("c - Change item quantity");
        System.out.println("i - Output items' descriptions");
        System.out.println("o - Output shopping cart");
        System.out.println("q - Quit");
        System.out.println();

        while(true){

                System.out.println("Choose an option:");
                if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                    choice = sc.nextLine().charAt(0);
                }
                if (choice != 'a' && choice != 'd' && choice != 'c' && choice != 'i' && choice != 'o' && choice != 'q'){
                    //An invalid choice is made
                    //Prompt for choice again
                    System.out.println("Choose an option:");
                    if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                        choice = sc.nextLine().trim().charAt(0);
                    }
                }
                else {
                    switch (choice) {
                        case 'c' : {

                            String name = "";
                            int qty = 0;

                            System.out.println("CHANGE ITEM QUANTITY");
                            System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                name = sc.nextLine();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Enter the new quantity:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                qty = sc.nextInt();
                            }
                            ItemToPurchase modItem = new ItemToPurchase();
                            modItem.setName(name);
                            modItem.setQuantity(qty);

                            cart.modifyItem(modItem);

                            choice = ' ';
                            System.out.println("");
                            break;
                        }
                        case 'o': {
                            System.out.println("OUTPUT SHOPPING CART");
                            cart.printTotal();
                            choice = ' ';
                            break;
                        }

                        case 'i': {
                            System.out.println("OUTPUT ITEMS' DESCRIPTIONS");
                            cart.printDescriptions();
                            choice = ' ';
                            break;
                        }

                        case 'a': {
                            String name = "";
                            String desc = "";
                            int price = 0;
                            int qty = 0;
                            System.out.println("ADD ITEM TO CART");
                            System.out.println("Enter item name:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                name = sc.nextLine();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Enter item description:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                desc = sc.nextLine();
                            }
                            System.out.println("Enter item price:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                price = sc.nextInt();
                                sc.nextLine();
                            }

                            System.out.println("Enter item quantity:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                qty = sc.nextInt();
                                sc.nextLine();
                            }
                            ItemToPurchase itemToPurchase = new ItemToPurchase(name, price, qty, desc);
                            cart.addItem(itemToPurchase);
                            choice = ' ';
                            break;
                        }

                        case 'd': {
                            String itemToRemove = " ";
                            System.out.println("REMOVE ITEM FROM CART");
                            System.out.println("Enter name of item to remove:");
                            if(sc.hasNextLine()) {
                                itemToRemove = sc.nextLine().trim().toString();
                            }
                            cart.removeItem(itemToRemove);
                            choice = ' ';
                            break;

                        }
                        case 'q': {
                            break;
                        }
                    }
            }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: Probably EOF reached.

Comment: just a side note, there is no reason to call toString() after nextLine() because nextLine() returns a string

Answer (score 0):

You have no terminating condition for your while() loop in your printMenu() method. I'm assuming you should exit when your user enters 'q'. Try this

Change:

```
while(true){
```

To:

```
boolean printTheMenu = true;
while(printTheMenu){
```

Then inside your switch statement for 'q' do the following

```
case 'q': {
    printTheMenu = false; //terminate the while loop
    break;
}
```

Your original code only breaks you out of the switch statment and not the while loop. Now your program will exit when the user enters 'q'